# Create a custom Windows 7 login

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

What I would like to do is to make my own logon provider in c++ instead of using the windows 7 login. Every time I look this up on Google they're talking about how to change the shutdown buttons or change the background which is not what I want to do.

What I would like to do for windows 7 would be the same exact way with windows xp which uses  gina.dll for its logon interface which windows vista and 7 no longer uses.

As I said I just want to create my own custom logon screen for windows 7.

Comment: It's possible, but it's a lot of work, and it's also risky. If you install a faulty login handler, you've basically hosed the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`ICredentialProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to customize the logon screen.

See [Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) in the January 2007 issue of MSDN magazine for an overview of how to implement a credential provider.